# How to use beautiful soup to parse this xml file?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to parse xml files, I tried reading the documentation of BS at Crummy but could not find anything satisfying for xml parsing. Right now, I've been able to figure only this much out:

```
file = open("input.xml")
page = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "xml")
for word in soup.findAll('word'):
    word_attr = dict(word.attrs)
    netag = word.find('ner')
    nertag = dict(netag)
    print ("STOP", nertag['ner'])
```

But, it is not doing anything.
My xml file is of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <document>
  <sentences>
   <sentence id="1">
    <tokens>
     <token id="1">
      <word>
       Starbucks
      </word>
      <lemma>
       Starbucks
      </lemma>
      <CharacterOffsetBegin>
       0
      </CharacterOffsetBegin>
      <CharacterOffsetEnd>
       9
      </CharacterOffsetEnd>
      <POS>
       NNP
      </POS>
      <NER>
       ORGANIZATION
      </NER>
     </token>
     <token id="2">
      <word>
       to
      </word>
      <lemma>
       to
      </lemma>
      <CharacterOffsetBegin>
       10
      </CharacterOffsetBegin>
      <CharacterOffsetEnd>
       12
      </CharacterOffsetEnd>
      <POS>
       TO
      </POS>
      <NER>
       O
      </NER>
     </token>
<token id="5">
  <word>
   .
  </word>
  <lemma>
   .
  </lemma>
  <CharacterOffsetBegin>
   263
  </CharacterOffsetBegin>
  <CharacterOffsetEnd>
   264
  </CharacterOffsetEnd>
  <POS>
   .
  </POS>
  <NER>
   O
  </NER>
 </token>
 </tokens>
   </sentence>
  </sentences>
 </document>
</root>
```

What I am trying to do is to extract the NER values, remove the period punctuation with "STOP", and write this to another txt file.

Like for a sentence: `Starbucks in New York is good.` (Written in an xml)
Should give: `ORGANIZATION in LOCATION is good STOP`

Can somebody please help me how to do this? Or provide me with sufficient documentation for Beautiful Soup xml parsing?

Comment: You are looking for `NER` tags *in the `word` tags*. They are not child tags but siblings.

Comment: If you have XML, why do you want to use Beautiful Soup? Python already comes with a perfectly good set of XML parsing methods.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters then how should I do this?

Comment: @JimGarrison Beautiful Soup is for that purpose only I suppose. To read xml files. :O

Comment: @MarthaPears: no, it is built for **HTML** files, actually. It can do XML as well, but there are some warts.

Comment: BS is designed to read messed up HTML the way a browser does it.  For XML the builtin facilities are much better.

Comment: Okayy. Now, I'm confused. Then how should I parse it otherwise?

Comment: Could you tell me some built in facilities?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for a sibling tag; either a next or previous sibling would be fine, at which point it'll just be easier to go the parent first:

```
for word in soup.find_all('word'):
    ner = word.parent.find('NER')
    if not ner: continue
    print '{} in {} is good'.format(ner.string.strip(), word.string.strip())
```

Demo:

```
>>> for word in soup.find_all('word'):
...     ner = word.parent.find('NER')
...     if not ner: continue
...     print '{} in {} is good'.format(ner.string.strip(), word.string.strip())
... 
ORGANIZATION in Starbucks is good
O in to is good
O in . is good
```

You could just use the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for this task however; it is just as capable of processing XML as BeautifulSoup is. Since you evidently already have lxml installed, you can use their ElementTree implementation.